# What is an npm "modular build", and how do I mount it?

Tags: typescript, npm, vuejs2, sortablejs

My goal is to use sortablejs's MultiDrag feature with Vuejs2 and Typescript.

The [docs](https://github.com/SortableJS/sortablejs/wiki/Dragging-Multiple-Items-in-Sortable) say:

> MultiDrag is a plugin for SortableJS, and is not included in all of
> Sortable's builds. It is available out of the box in the main
> Sortable.js file, but is not mounted by default in the modular builds
> (except for in sortable.complete.esm.js). To mount it from a modular
> build, simply follow this code:

```
import { Sortable, MultiDrag } from 'sortablejs';

Sortable.mount(new MultiDrag());
```

I found [sortable.complete.esm.js](https://github.com/SortableJS/sortablejs/blob/master/modular/sortable.complete.esm.js) in the repo, but I can't figure out where to place it in my project's directory structure so that the import statement above works.

I've tried

```
% npm install ~/gitrepos/sortablejs/modular/sortable.complete.esm.js 
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install "../../../../sortablejs/modular/sortable.complete.esm.js" as it is not a directory and is not a file with a name ending in .tgz, .tar.gz or .tar
```

I tried copying the file into my `/node_modules` dir, then:

```
import { Sortable, MultiDrag } from "sortablejs";
```

fails with:

This dependency was not found:

```
* sortablejs in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--14-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Pages.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
```

How do I mount this file?

=======================UPDATE============================

I followed dwosk's advice below, and this is the error I see:

```
 warning  in ./src/main2.ts

"export 'MultiDrag' was not found in 'sortablejs'

ERROR in /Users/jeff/gitrepos/code/code/paidmerge/from-vue/src/main2.ts(11,10):
11:10 'Sortable' can only be imported by using a default import.
     9 | import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
    10 | 
  > 11 | import { Sortable, MultiDrag } from 'sortablejs';
       |          ^
    12 | 
    13 | Sortable.mount(new MultiDrag());
    14 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the `sortablejs` module.

```
npm install sortablejs
```

Then in your `.ts` file just like the docs:

```
import { Sortable, MultiDrag } from 'sortablejs';

Sortable.mount(new MultiDrag());
```

"mount" is specific to the `sortablejs` library and isn't a typescript-specific term. Per the docs, `MultiDrag` is "...is available out of the box in the main Sortable.js file..."

Comment: Thank you dwosk.  I ran `npm install sortablejs` and it succeeded.  Then I copied in the code, and I get this error: ``` warning  in ./src/main2.ts

"export 'MultiDrag' was not found in 'sortablejs'

ERROR in /Users/jeff/gitrepos/code/code/paidmerge/from-vue/src/main2.ts(11,10):
11:10 'Sortable' can only be imported by using a default import.
     9 | import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
    10 | 
  > 11 | import { Sortable, MultiDrag } from 'sortablejs';
       |          ^
    12 | 
    13 | Sortable.mount(new MultiDrag());
    14 | ```

Comment: try `import Sortable, { MultiDrag } from "sortablejs";`

Comment: Thanks for your help dwosk.  The docs for the library have fallen well behind the API itself.